# How to access the sim card sent items in AT COMMANDS using JAVA

Tags: java, at-command

I'm using AT COMMANDS to send sms in Java and I want my program to show if all the messages was sent or not. But I don't know how to view the sent items of sim card. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Here are some of the codes I'm using:

```
 String contact=rs.getString("contactNo");
 String number = "AT+CMGW="+qu + contact + qu + "\r\n";
 message =content+ cz + "\r";
 outStream.write(number.getBytes());
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 outStream.write(message.getBytes());
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 System.out.println(contact);
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information to go on. Some code, the name of the libraries you're using, etc.

Comment: I added some of my codes :)